# What's the difference between these two local variables?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, constants, local

```
const std::string  s1("foo");
const std::string& s2("foo");
```

Not sure how they are different but I'm seeing evidence of both usages.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is this question actually about? You never heard about references? Or you actually know what references are, but never saw a reference initialized that way? In the former case you need to read some book on C++ first. Trying to learn basic features of the language by asking questions about unfamiliar syntax is not exactly a productive approach.

Comment: @AndreyT I'm am relatively new to the language but I'm wondering what subtleties exist between the two instantiations.  I haven't at least in my experience come across the 2nd example and was wondering on its use.

Comment: Useless trivia:  there's a defect in the current C++ language standard that declares that only objects can be variables.  Since `s2` is a reference, not an object, it is technically not a variable.  This defect is fixed in the next, forthcoming version of the C++ language standard, C++0x.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Which shows how applying standardese is often unhelpful. :)

Comment: @Fred:  I agree.  I did prefix it with "useless trivia," since that really is quite useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const std::string s1("foo");
```

This declares a named `std::string` object as a local variable.

```
const std::string& s1("foo");
```

This declares a const reference to a `std::string` object.  An unnamed, temporary `std::string` object is created with the contents `"foo"` and the reference is bound to that temporary object.  The temporary object will exist until the reference goes out of scope.

In this particular case, there is no observable difference between the two:  in both cases you end up with a `std::string` that can be accessed via the name `s1` and which will be destroyed when `s1` goes out of scope.

However, in some cases, there is a difference.  Consider, for example, a function that returns by reference:

```
const std::string& get_reference_to_string();
```

If you initialize `s1` with the result of calling this function, there is a difference between:

```
const std::string s1(get_reference_to_string());
const std::string& s1(get_reference_to_string());
```

In the first case, a copy of the referenced string is made and used to initialize `s1`.  In the second case, `s1` is simply bound to the `std::string` to which the returned reference refers:  no copy is made.

Answer (score 3):

They are identical in meaning, due to the way constant references can bind to temporaries plus string having an implicit conversion from char*.

For clarity and readability, prefer the non-reference.

Comment: Fred, you're a machine!  Do you know any resources that might delve into this a little deeper? Would like to know more about what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Would the second example create a long-lived reference to the object so if you pass it in somewhere else that keeps a reference it will stay valid as opposed to the first example only having local scope?

Comment: @chriskirk: No, beyond the implementation detail of copy elision (which can be disregarded due to the diligent effort of the writers of all decent C++ compilers), they are identical in meaning.  If you change the source ("foo") to something else (as in James' answer) or change the type to something else (as I tried to say in my answer), the meaning might change.

Comment: I don't see why a nonexistent or inaccessible copy constructor would render the reference initialization invalid:  no copy is ever made.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: You're right; I was confused with copy-initialization (C++03 §8.5p12), but it applies to the non-reference form.

Answer (score 0):

The first instance creates a constant string variable initialized to hold "foo". The second one creates a constant reference to a string and then initializes that constant reference to point at a temporary string that was initialized to hold "foo".

Answer (score 0):

`const std::string s1("foo");` creates a `std::string` object on the stack and initializes it with the `const char*` string "foo." `const std::string& s1("foo")`, on the other hand, is a *const reference* to an implicitly constructed `std::string`.

Comment: It's a bad idea in that it is a bit confusing to read. But other than that it it's perfectly valid code and it does not create dangling references.